# CallbackFilterIterator and Prime numbers generation issue

Tags: php, iterator

I'm trying to use the [PHP \CallbackFilterIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.callbackfilteriterator.php) working in a script that prints Prime numbers.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is a very basic [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), see this nice [video from Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jwV3zxXc8E).

Here's the simplified version of the code

```
<?php

/**
 * Run this code with: php -n to make sure no configuration will be used
 * so xdebug will not be used either.
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

function llist($n = 2) {
    yield $n;
    return yield from llist($n + 1);
}

$callback = fn(int $p) => fn(int $a, int $b, Iterator $it): bool => $a % $p !== 0;

$i = 0;
$iterator = llist();
while (true) {
    $prime = $iterator->current();

    $iterator->next();

    var_dump($prime);

    if ($i++ > 100) {
        break;
    }

    $iterator = new CallbackFilterIterator(
        $iterator,
        $callback($prime)
    );
}
```

(*also available on Gist: https://gist.github.com/drupol/8a1ff3c4d5ccbb56a1e45823677a9b38*)

The script generate first an integer Iterator (*from 2 to infinity*), then, at each loop the iterator is overridden with a new `\CallbackFilterIterator` and a new filter callback.

This script should print out Prime numbers, starting with `2`, but after printing `2` for some unknown reasons yet, it end up with a `Fatal error`:

```
 $ php -n primes.php
int(2)
NULL
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to {closure}() must be of the type int, null given, called in /home/pol/dev/git/primes.php on line 32 and defined in /home/pol/dev/git/primes.php:15
Stack trace:
#0 /home/pol/dev/git/primes.php(32): {closure}()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/pol/dev/git/primes.php on line 15
```

I don't know yet what I'm doing wrong, this is why I'm posting my message here, any clue is welcome.

Comment: You need to call `$iterator->next();` at the end of your loop, as `next()` needs to be called once for an iterator to yield its first value. I'm not familiar with that particular algorithm though so I can't really comment on whether this is the best approach.

Comment: I tried that already, and it seems to produce something good, but there are missing prime numbers in the list.

Comment: Sorry forget what I said, it's working if I remove the first call to next() !

Comment: Ah, yes, that too, since otherwise it'll be called twice in a row.

Comment: yes exactly. Here's the final version: https://gist.github.com/drupol/8513c7bfdbe1ad7d66fa710f51a21b32

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to move the call to `next()` under the `new CallbackFilterIterator`.

Here's the final version: https://gist.github.com/drupol/8513c7bfdbe1ad7d66fa710f51a21b32

Thanks @jeto !